# I am doing cross validation of a simple multiple regression in R with the cvTools package, and I am getting an error every time

Tags: r, performance-testing, linear-regression, cross-validation, economics

I have created a very simple multiple regression econometrics model with the following codes:

```
regression<-lm(y ~ q1 + spread + home + ff, mraf8)
```

This simple econometrics model has 49 quarterly observations.  Next, I want to do a cross validation with 7 folds.  So, I enter the following codes:

```
cvFit(regression, data = mraf8, y = "y", cost = rmse, K = 7, R = 1, foldType = c("consecutive"))
```

And, I get the following error:

```
Error in cvFit.call(call, data = data, x = x, y = y, cost = cost, K = K,  : = 'data' must have 49 observations
```

Somehow, cvFit() does not seem to recognize my data name mraf8.  So, next I put my data name in quotes as shown below:

```
cvFit(regression, data = "mraf8", y = "y", cost = rmse, K = 7, R = 1, foldType = c("consecutive"))
```

And, I get the following error:

```
Error in cvFolds(n, K, R, type = foldType) : 'K' outside allowable range
```

How can K fold 7 be outside of the range of a model with 49 observations?

Can you help me with this specific coding?

Comment: try `y=mraf8$y` as `?cvFit` seems to suggest it want a value vector / matrix not a string. More generally, have a look at the examples at the bottom of the help page to see how to correctly specify the function.

Comment: The coding errors suggest the problem is not so much with my specification of "y".  It is the the K fold 7 being outside of range.  Still unclear why that would be the case.

Comment: the second error occurs due to the arguments that you are passing not being sensible (ive not looked into the code to see why): do not quote the data and y arguments.

Comment: An example: `library(cvTools) ; m = lm(mpg ~ wt + disp, mtcars) ; 
cvFit(m, data = mtcars, y = mtcars$mpg, cost =  rtmspe)` which works as expected. These misspecified models give the errors that you see: `cvFit(m, data = mtcars, y = "mpg", cost =  rtmspe) ; cvFit(m, data = "mtcars", y = "mpg", cost =  rtmspe)`

Comment: Thanks you prooved your point very well.  I will have to try this correction tomorrow when I am back at work.  Thanks again.

Comment: user20650, your suggestion did work.  And, your comments made up for a rather lacking package documentation.  I encourage you to formulate your comments into an official answer.  I would readily give you a thumbs up and best answer.